# How can I make a custom post type that loops pages in a new dashboard page, each single page is a new dashboard page (all within the back-end)?

Tags: custom-post-types, dashboard, cms, post-type

I've been wanting to make the most out of WordPress, to use it more and more like a CMS as it truly is a wonderful project. Out of all the CMS/Blogging webapps, WordPress wins in my book.

I understand how to create a post-type. What I don't understand is how to make pages within the dashboard, and how to add a sidebar menu item with the links. Also, I would like to know how to make the new posts of the custom post-type display only on the dashboard, as a back-end documentation base, or CRM. Of course I could always use a plugin, but then the opportunity for not only myself to learn would be lost, the opportunity to show the many visitors of this site how to achieve the same thing would be lost as well.

Let the Answers begin!

P.S. I'm so very grateful for all of the help you all give to the community here. I've searched for this topic and couldn't find it, if this topic is already answered here, please comment with the link to the question with the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by dashboard page. Cause when you add a CPT, it has its own menu on admin page.

Comment: What I mean is to have a custom post type for pages that are only displayed in the dashboard. Like a dashboard blog, the intent is to store documentation for site users on the back-end of a wordpress website. I know I can simply make the post-types private, but the need is to not visit the front-end at all. Users will view all the documentation pages from the back-end, the dashboard. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: basically so that the front-end of the website serves the visitors, the back-end of the site serves the users of the site

Comment: I still don't quite get why you would want your CPT blog on your backend. As what wordpress is, you add data on backend, you view it on frontend. And, isn't what you have added already view-able on it's editor?

Comment: Although I suspect what is, it is not very clear for me what you are trying to achieve... If you want a storm of answers, I suggest reading all Related Links that appear in [ask], they are quite a worth read. :::: You can [use the admin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13795805/1287812) to display almost anything. [This plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wedevs-project-manager/) uses an interesting concept, may be worth studying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress isn't built with your idea in mind. That being said, [add_menu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) on the WordPress Codex shows how to create an admin top-level menu page, i.e., a menu item within the left column of the admin section. [add_submenu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) shows how to create submenus of top-level menu items.

You could [create a plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin), and add menu/submenu items. Creating a plugin, in and of itself, is exceedingly simple:

```
<?php
// Plugin Name: My Cool Plugin
```

Upload that to your `wp-content/plugins/your-plugin-directory` directory, that's all it takes. It's a little more involved to create the menu/submenu items, but those links are a good place to start. But, there's no built-in functionality that I'm aware of that will allow you to easily do what you want. A ready-made plugin *might* exist, but I haven't searched.

BTW, custom post types wouldn't figure into the equation, those are for front-end only.

#### Edit

[WP Help](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-help/) is a plugin that might do the trick.

Comment: You're most welcome :)